# ColdFusion: force browser to download file and still load the page

Tags: coldfusion, http-headers, mime-types, attachment

I have an `test.cfm` where I dynamically build a pdf-File and output it with `<cfheader>` and `<cfcontent>` to the browser, but I still want the page to load and show "test html":

```
<CFFILE action="readbinary" file="#expandpath("./test.cfm")#" variable="testcontent" />
<CFHEADER name="Content-Disposition" value="attachment; filename=""test.txt""; charset=utf-8">
<CFCONTENT type="text/plain" reset="yes" variable="#testcontent#">

<CFCONTENT type="text/html" reset="yes" /><!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Testdoc</title>
</head>
<body>test html</body>
</html>
```

(outputting the file itself is just for the example)

Is there a way to accomplish this?

Comment: Load the page, then have a HTML meta redirect to the download?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't trigger what happens after a download, but you can do it the other way round - load the page you want, then redirect to the file to download using a HTML meta redirect:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="5; url=http://domain.com/path/to/download" />
```

(If necessary, you can use [cfhtmlhead](http://cfdocs.cfhtmlhead) to insert that into the relevant part of an existing HTML page.)

The 5 is the number of seconds to wait - setting to 0 will redirect immediately. (When using with other pages, using an instant redirect can cause issues with the back button; should be less of an issue for downloads though.)